# Parallel connection without resistance with series connection with resistance

Tags: short-circuit

Question is simple: Is this a short circuit and why?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxSZKy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The reason I'm asking is because Falstad circuit simulator marks [this circuit](http://falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgpABZsKBTAWjDACgAncDQkPKmjTx8qVMHDYB3br34yQ2BCihsAbrSEKlG4XNG0qSfTART5i5YOEWV0sDxEhis0Wedbl93jchuXT721fAHsoEEIaMJpIUmoYSCMQZSpsNmxhKgAxCDFkCBYQACUGAGcASxKAFwBDADsAYwY2IA) with an error message "wire loop detected".

Even theoretically, but considering a material world - i.e., not equations, but a wire with literally zero resistance?

I really tried to search such situation, including here, but all questions are just about only parallel connections.

Comment: Is *what* a short circuit? Please label your nodes and specify where exactly you're looking at for a short circuit.

Comment: @brhans, I just was playing with Falstad circuit simulator, and it stated that it is a short circuit, so I asked about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a short circuit and why?

No it isn’t a short-circuit. The path length of the circuit is not shortened. The phrase is intended to describe a zero ohm connection between two nodes that bypasses one or more elements of a larger network that reduces the overall length of the current path(s) of a closed circuit.

In the example, the circuit does not change.

Comment: So, as theoretically, as well as in experiment there will be just 5mA current per parallel branch?

Comment: I'd say the current in the individual parallel wires are indeterminate, because you are dividing zero by zero: zero voltage drop by zero resistance. The only thing you can definitely say is the sum is 10mA.

Answer (score 0):

> *Is this a short circuit and why?*

No it isn't a short-circuit because it hasn't applied a short-cut to any necessary current path.

If an applied zero ohm connection neither alters functionality nor circuit performance then it can't be described as a short-circuit. In other words, a short-circuit must do something (usually bad or not wanted).

Of course we may be dealing with semantics here but, that's how I see it.

Comment: Simulators state, that it is short-circuit, for example http://falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html

Comment: So, as theoretically, as well as in experiment there will be just 5mA current per parallel branch?

Comment: @Stdugnd4ikbd A short circuit, by definition, is a connection that forces two points to have equal potential and alter the incoming/outgoing current's path. In your case, those nodes are already at equal potential and the current already flows from R1 to V1, so another branch doesn't make them shorted.

Comment: @Stdugnd4ikbd Falsenad is really just a hobbyist toy and I don't expect any definition that relies on it is worth much. If we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Comment: @Stdugnd4ikbd: Falstad may see that loop as a short circuit, but most of us will just say you have an extra or unnecessary wire there.